# what is the annual yield in percentage for the following scenario?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If the annual interest rate for an investment is 20 percent, compounded 4 times a year, what is the approximate effective annual yield?

For this problem I would use the formula A= P(1+r/n)^(n*t) to find out the A(=interest) but I am missing the P ( principal) here. I also know that r=0.2 and n=4.

I also have other formulas such as I = p*r*t and A= P*e^(r*t) but I don't think they apply here.

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you were given APR and asked to find APY, if so ${20\over 4}$ is the percentage per quarter which gives a quarterly value of 1.05. $(1.05)^4$ is roughly 1.215 rounded down to the nearest 1000th so 21.5 %

Comment: thanks for helping me get the correct answer. Would you mind explaining how you came up with the quarterly value of 1.05 and then how did you convert 1.215 to 21.5%?

Comment: the second part of your comment is  simply took 1.215 = 121.5%  and cut off the 1 leaving 21.5% ( admittedly I plugged the math into a computer algebra system because I was too lazy).  APR is the amount without compounding that's given as 20% with compounding 4 times a year each quarter getting an equal amount of that 20% is 5% so it compounds at 5% per quarter. $1.05^4 $ is roughly 1.215  http://www.investopedia.com/articles/basics/04/102904.asp  may help .